# Why am I getting Error on Shiny Host but not local

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shinyapp, with tabs, that takes a dataframe and allows the user to filter it - then create a histogram based on the filters.  This app works great when I run it on my local machine.  However, When I publish it to shinyapps.io I get the following error:

```
ERROR: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I understand from other posts that the dataframe needs to be reactive or may need to be reactive?  However when I enclose the data frame in reactive like so:

```
dat <- reactive(df)
```

I get the same error.

The files are located at [github](https://github.com/jvondie/shinypro)

or here:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
#server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df <- read.csv('orioles.csv') 
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    dat <- df
    if (input$opp != "All") {
      dat <- dat[dat$Opponent == input$opp,]
    }
    if (input$prk != "All") {
      dat <- dat[dat$parkId == input$prk,]
    }
    if (input$strt != "All") {
      dat <- dat[dat$Day.or.Night == input$strt,]
    }
    dat
  }))
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    dat <- df
    if (input$opp != "All") {
      dat <- dat[dat$Opponent == input$opp,]
    }
    if (input$prk != "All") {
      dat <- dat[dat$parkId == input$prk,]
    }
    if (input$strt != "All") {
      dat <- dat[dat$Day.or.Night == input$strt,]
    }
    hist(dat$BAL_SCORE, main = "Based on Filters", xlab = "Runs", ylab = "Frequency of runs scored", breaks = 20, col = "orange" )

  })
})
```

UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


navbarPage(
  title = 'Navigation', 
  tabPanel('Data Table', fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Baltimore Orioles Game Results from 2010-2015"),

  # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("opp",
                       "Opponent:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(df$Opponent))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("prk",
                       "Ball Park:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(df$parkId))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("strt",
                       "Day or Night Game:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(df$Day.or.Night))))
    )
  ),
  # Create a new row for the table.
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)),
  tabPanel('Runs', fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Runs Scored in filtered games"),
    fluidRow(
          column(6,
             plotOutput("plot1", width = 800, height = 600)
    )
    )
  ))
)
```

Comment: The closure error usually comes from trying to use the df-function instead of a data.frame called df. My guess would be to check that you load df correctly, you can try this by calling something like print(df) after you have loaded it. Does that return anythin useful?

Comment: I realized it was running locally cause I had loaded the data set into my environment.  When I run the app without the data set loaded into the environment it does not work.  I guess I'm unclear how to load the csv file to run with shiny app

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a more concise code using `reactive` and combining your subsetting conditions:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  df <- read.csv('orioles.csv') 
  dat <- reactive(
    df[(input$opp == "All" | df$Opponent == input$opp) &
       (input$prk != "All" | df$parkId == input$prk) &
       (input$strt != "All"| df$Day.or.Night == input$strt),])

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(dat()))
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(dat()$BAL_SCORE, main = "Based on Filters", xlab = "Runs", 
         ylab = "Frequency of runs scored", breaks = 20, col = "orange" )
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried this as well as tried updating the "dat" calls within "sat" to "sat".  Both did not work.

Comment: sorry I miswrote `dat` in `sat`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my App Working.  The error was occuring because the data frame was not loading the way I had it set up.  Solution is posted on github link shown above.